# How to make Java release all the memory upon System.exit(0)?

Tags: java, winapi, memory-leaks

Our app is a mix of Java and native code. And it leaks memory.

The most probable cause is the native code and indeed it has its share of leaks, however, they  do not seem to be the only contributor.

Anyway, I profile the app with a native profiler, using a build of OpenJDK 6 that I did locally, hence I have full sources and full symbols for Java itself.

The methodology is simple - I run the app and then at some point I signal it to terminate gracefully. The graceful termination includes three steps:

1. Signaling the native code to clean up.
2. Stopping the http server (Restlet + Simple)
3. Calling System.exit(0)

Apparently, Java relies heavily on the OS to release the memory it has occupied, because I can see several calls to VirtualAlloc to reserve some memory, but it is never unreserved.

But it is just an example, there are plenty of committed unreleased memory and there is no way to determine what is left behind on purpose for the OS to release and what is a leak. Now, I do not blame Java, these leaks might be the result of us doing something wrong. I do not know.

**An important note.** I am not talking about cleaning up during the lifetime of the process. There are questions on SO dealing with it and none of them is relevant to mine. I want Java to clean up upon exit, to see how much memory truly leaks.

So, is there a way to tell Java to clean up upon exit in order to make this post mortem leak analysis feasible?

Comment: How will you distinguish the well-behaved memory from the leaky stuff?  Better to get a good profiler and not write anything yourself.

Comment: I would attempt to determine which portions were created by Java but can be ignored.  Java tends to allocate large blocks from the start, this should give you some idea which onces are Java and which ones are created by your program.  Also can you test the JNI code stand alone (without Java)?

Comment: You say that the native code you use has its "share of leaks", why don't you fix these first? Also, releasing resources of a `native`-backed class is one of the few cases where `finalize()` can actually help, provided you have a reference to the native method freeing resources (but even if you do so, always remember to call `super.finalize()`).

Comment: I'm no OS whiz, so I'm wondering, but doesn't `System.exit()` terminate the process and thus the OS will release all memory reserved by that process anyway? If that's the case, I don't get the question.

Comment: I would ask the opposite question, how to make java to keep some memory, after System.exit().

Comment: @Jochen `System.exit()` terminates the JVM and therefore, yes, the process, and (theoretically) all OS resources associated with that process. If the memory analysis has been performed post `System.exit()` then this looks like an OS leak, in which case, good luck!

Comment: The native profiler I am using (Memory Validator) creates a report before OS releases all the resources. It acts on the assumption that a well behaved application takes responsibility for the memory it allocates and makes sure to release it without relying on the OS. This is good practice anyway. OS releases all the resources, of course. But if you peek at the allocated memory before that, then all you have is either leaks or deliberately left pieces (usually a bad practice).

Comment: @mark I dispute that what your tool expects is 'good practice'. The last time I worried about releasing all memory prior to exiting a process was 1993, and that was because of a poorly written operating system. I would say that your tool's expectations are *grossly* unrealistic and are causing you significant pain and cost to absolutely zero purpose, and I recommend that you ditch it forthwith. In any case you will *never* be able to get Java to behave as expected. Assuming you have correctly describes the tool.

Answer (score 0):

A good java profiler (e.g. YourKit or JProfiler) will tell you, straight-up, if you are leaking java objects by holding references. This will answer your question about non-JNI leaks.

For JNI leaks, (and I write from experience), you need to make sure that your native code can be tested *outside of java*, so that the potential for in-Java-specific linkage is small, and you can deal with it by careful reading. Or talking to a Rubber Duck.